# Como deixar meu app aberto esperando o servidor mandar informação

Tags: android, socket, cliente-servidor

Estou criando um app cliente que assim que mudar status de algum componente no servidor o servidor mandara para o cliente para que o usuário possa visualizar.Preciso que o app fique aberto recebendo informação e sempre que usuario abrir deve colocar seu login, senha e mandar para servidor para fazer primeira conexão com isso o app fique em segundo plano e so fechar quando o usuario não for utilizar mais e ir na opção de sair colocada no app. Gostaria de uma dica de como posso fazer isso, oque devo pesquisar ou algum tutorial.

pretendo fazer algo parecido com o modelo desse app 
[aNag](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.degois.damien.android.aNag&hl=pt_BR)

Comment: Guilherme, de uma olhada no GCM do google. Nem precisa deixar o app aberto para ser notificado.

Comment: Isso pode ser feito com webSockets, e depende da tecnologia do servidor utilizado. Deê uma olhada [neste link](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) para entender a tecnologia e [nest outro link](http://jwebsocket.org/about-jws/Press-Articles/android/introduction-websockets-android) para um componente Android com suporte a webSockets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guilherme,

na verdade deixar apps e threads rodando em background com conexoes abertas não é recomendado. Imagina se toda app ficasse com uma porta aberta e uma conexão estabelecida esperando uma resposta do servidor? Em um ambiente mobile onde muitas vezes a conexao 3G é muito lenta, isso congestionaria a rede, e o usuário não conseguiria navegar eficientemente. Então, a partir daí, a Google criou um barramento de servidores que fazem essa comunicação para nós, evitando assim o congestionamento em caso que a conexão com a internet seja muito ruim.

Esse barramente é chamado de GCM (Google Cloud Messaging), citado nos comentários pelo nosso amigo Wakim.

Funciona da seguinte maneira:

1. A app registra na sua conta do GCM e é gerada uma Key
2. sua app deve entregar essa Key para o seu servidor que deseja comunicar com a app
3. O servidor envia uma notificação para o servidores GCM com a Key da sua aplicação
4. O GCM enfileira as notificações e entrega elas ao seu celular
5. O serviço de notificação do seu celular entrega a notificação ao seu código.

Ou seja, os servidores comunicam com o GCM e o GCM com seu celular, isso faz com que o celular só precise que uma conexao fique aberta: a do GCM. Isso me permite escalabilidade e evita problemas de conexao. É assim que apps do facebook e whatsapp funcionam. Sua app não precisa ficar aberta, e não precisa de threads em background escutando conexões, você só precisa configurar um serviço na sua app e o sistema operacional faz o resto.

Obviamente minha explicação é bem breve, e bem superficial. Você pode encontrar mais detalhes sobre isso [AQUI](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html), com explicações de como implementar a parte do cliente e a parte do servidor e muito mais.

Você também pode encontrar um vídeo tutorial muito bem explicativo [AQUI](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmzv716SYkQ).

Espero ter ajudado!!!

Comment: Muito obrigado! ajudou muito estou estudando o GCM para poder implementá-lo corretamente. e vlw pelo esclarecimento