# Chat com notificações na aplicação

Tags: android, socket, app, chat

Tenho uma aplicação Android que por dentro dela, o usuário pode enviar mensagem para o administrador(eu). Eu queria fazer uma coisa mais legal nessa comunicação, gostaria de que quando eu respondesse a mensagem, aparecesse no aplicativo que ele tem uma nova mensagem não lida, ou seja, recebe como uma notificação.

Estava pensando em algumas possíveis soluções, mas acho que não deve ser a ideal, iria fazer algo assim:
Dentro o meu app iria fazer uma Thread que ficasse a cada segundo consultando um banco de dados e verificando se tem alguma coluna de uma tabela que esteja com status de não lido, caso sim mudava o meu app. Acredito que não seja o melhor a se fazer e acho que não ficaria tão fácil assim a implementação.

Alguém sabe uma maneira de se fazer isso?

Comment: Não estou a ver outra forma de fazer, acho que tens mesmo de ter uma threar a correr.

Comment: Não sei se é bem isso que vc quer, mas de uma olhada em http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: Isso mesmo Paulo, obrigado

Answer (score 5):

Na verdade deixar apps e threads rodando em background com conexoes abertas não é recomendado. Imagina se toda app ficasse com uma porta aberta e uma conexão estabelecida esperando uma resposta do servidor? Em um ambiente mobile onde muitas vezes a conexao 3G é muito lenta, isso congestionaria a rede, e o usuário não conseguiria navegar eficientemente. Então, a partir daí, a Google criou um barramento de servidores que fazem essa comunicação para nós, evitando assim o congestionamento em caso que a conexão com a internet seja muito ruim.

Esse barramente é chamado de GCM (Google Cloud Messaging), citado nos comentários pelo nosso amigo Wakim.

Funciona da seguinte maneira:

A app registra na sua conta do GCM e é gerada uma Key

sua app deve entregar essa Key para o seu servidor que deseja comunicar com a app

O servidor envia uma notificação para o servidores GCM com a Key da sua aplicação

O GCM enfileira as notificações e entrega elas ao seu celular

O serviço de notificação do seu celular entrega a notificação ao seu código.

Ou seja, os servidores comunicam com o GCM e o GCM com seu celular, isso faz com que o celular só precise que uma conexao fique aberta: a do GCM. Isso me permite escalabilidade e evita problemas de conexao. É assim que apps do facebook e whatsapp funcionam. Sua app não precisa ficar aberta, e não precisa de threads em background escutando conexões, você só precisa configurar um serviço na sua app e o sistema operacional faz o resto.

Obviamente minha explicação é bem breve, e bem superficial. Você pode encontrar mais detalhes sobre isso [AQUI](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html), com explicações de como implementar a parte do cliente e a parte do servidor e muito mais.

Você também pode encontrar um vídeo tutorial muito bem explicativo [AQUI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmzv716SYkQ).

Espero ter ajudado!!!

Tive essa responde em uma pergunta minha espero ter ajudado.
fonte: [AQUI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22528/como-deixar-meu-app-aberto-esperando-o-servidor-mandar-informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)!

Comment: Apenas bancando o chato heheh, eu sei que você quis dizer "escutando conexão" no sentido de "dados sendo trafegados pela conexão", mas a rigor o que o GCM faz é manter uma conexão aberta com o servidor GCM (com direito a heartbeats entre aparelho e servidor para mantê-la aberta) e os dados úteis só trafegam conforme necessário, sem fazer _polling_. Questão de uso das palavras.

Comment: Eu estou dando uma lida no GCM e me parece ser a solução, ainda não comecei a implementa-lo, mas por exemplo, com ele é possivel de uma aplicação eu envie mensagem que vai para a web e seja salvo em algum banco e depois eu responda e a mensagem de resposta chegue no cliente?
Os tutoriais e materiais que achei só falam em troca envio de mensagem a partir da Web e nada como uma troca.

Comment: Vejo que minha resposta a pergunta do Guilherme se propagou. hauahauhauahau. A app do Whatsapp usa exatamente isso para poder trocar mensagens. Se vc implementar um servidor XMPP há sim possibilidade de troca de mensagens e não só de recebimento na app --> [GCM XMPP SERVER](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html)

Comment: haha compartilhando seus conhecimentos Ighor Augusto

Answer (score 4):

Bom, se sua aplicação consulta um banco de dados externo, você pode , ao invéz de fazer uma thread, fazer um serviço que faz justamente isso que você disse.

A diferença é que mesmo com a aplicação fechada e o usuário fazendo outras coisas ou mesmo com a tela desligada, você consegue notificá-lo que existe uma nova mensagem.

Tenha consciência que como seu aplicativo realiza a consulta em um banco de dados externo, talvez o intervalo de verificação deva ser igual ou superior a uma hora.

Exemplo de serviço:

```
public class MessageVerifyService extends Service
{
    private Handler serviceHandler;
    private Task myTask;
    NotificationManager notify;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
    {
        notify = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        myTask = new Task();
        serviceHandler = new Handler();
        serviceHandler.postDelayed(myTask,1000);

        return START_STICKY;

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        super.onDestroy();

        try
        {
            serviceHandler.removeCallbacks(myTask);
            serviceHandler = null;

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    public void showNotificationAlert(int numMensagens)
    {
        Intent intent= new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class); // coloque sua activity para ver as mensagens não lidas
        intent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Mensagens não Lidas",System.currentTimeMillis());
        PendingIntent i =PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0,intent,0);

        note.setLatestEventInfo(getBaseContext(),"Mensagens não lidas","Existem " + numMensagens + " mensagens não lidas",null);
        // Hide the notification after its selected
        note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND ;
        notify.cancel(0x1);//retira se houver
        notify.notify(0x1, note);
    }


    class Task implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            //VERIFICAR AQUI SE HÁ UMA NOVA MENSAGEM
            /*

             int numMens = verificarMensagensNaoLidas();
             if(numMens > 0)
                showNotificationAlert(numMens);


            */

            //executa de uma em uma hora
            serviceHandler.postDelayed(this,3600000);// 1 hora
        }


    }
}
```

**Pense também que se o usuário desligar o telefone, você deve voltar seu serviço de verificação, então implemente também uma classe Receiver:**

```
public class MessageVerifyServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private final String BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

         if(arg1.getAction().equals(BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION))
         {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(arg0, MessageVerifyService.class);
            arg0.startService(myIntent);
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "Serviço verificador de mensagens iniciado novamente!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

    }

}
```

Você precisa colocar esse código no AndroidManifest.xml:

**Permissão:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Declaração do serviço e receiver dentro da Tag application:

```
    <!-- SERVICES -->
    <service
            android:name=".MessageVerifyService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:process=":verifymessage" />

        <!-- RECEIVER QUE INICIA JUNTO COM O DISPOSITIVO -->
        <receiver
                android:name=".MessageVerifyServiceReceiver"
                android:exported="false"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:process=":receiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```